# ¿Como abrir otro Fragment pasandole variables en Adroid Studio, Java?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Estoy trabajando con markers de google maps y quiero abrir un fragment (markerFragment) con los valores de ese marker para mostrarlos posteriormente.

Tengo estos métodos para abrir markerFragment:

```
     public void onInfoWindowClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
        Snackbar.make(getView(), "onInfoWindowClick", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        loadFragments(marker);
    }



    public void loadFragments( Marker marker){
        String titulo = marker.getTitle();
        String descripcion = marker.getSnippet();


        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        markerFragment markerFragment = new markerFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, markerFragment);
        transaction.commit();

    }
   }
```

El problema es que no se como pasar las vartiables titulo y descripción.

Comment: Hola Adrián, como consejo los nombres de clases nombrarlas con mayúscula al  inicio, por ejemplo tu archivo lo debiste crear como MarkerFragment, es buena práctica, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes basarte en la documentación oficial

**[Cómo pasar datos entre fragmentos](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between?hl=es)**

[**Cómo comunicar contenido con otros fragmentos**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Los datos se envían dentro de un `bundle` que será enviado al `Fragment`. Se instancía el Fragment, se crea el bundle y este agrega a tu Fragment mediante el método [**setArguments()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)) .

```
public void loadFragments( Marker marker){
    String titulo = marker.getTitle();
    String descripcion = marker.getSnippet();

    //Agrega valores en bundle.
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("titulo", titulo);
    bundle.putString("descripcion", descripcion);

    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    markerFragment markerFragment = new markerFragment();

     //Agrega valores a Fragment usando el bundle.
     markerFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, markerFragment);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

**Recibir valores en Fragment.**

Para recibir los valores lo puedes realizar dentro del método `onCreate()` :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String titulo = getArguments().getString("titulo");    
    String descripcion = getArguments().getString("descripcion"); 
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

Pero también lo puedes realizar dentro del método `onCreateView()` y cuando se reconstruya el `Fragment` si deseas mantener los valores debes sobreescribir `onSaveInstanceState()`

```
private String titulo = "";
private String descripcion = "";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      titulo = getArguments().getString("titulo");    
      descripcion = getArguments().getString("descripcion"); 
      ...
      ...
      ...
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("titulo", titulo);
    outState.putString("descripcion", descripcion);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Puedes pasar tus parámetros a través de **Bundle**

> ***Haz globales*** tus variables **"titulo y descripcion"**

```
Este bloque lo puedes meter dentro de un método, o si lo prefieres en tu **onCreate()**

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.put("TITLE_KEY", titulo);
args.put("DESCRIPTION_KEY", descripcion);
MarkerFragment markerFragment = new MarkerFragment();
markerFragment.setArguments(args);
getFragmentManager().replace(R.id.container, markerMaps).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

> En tu método onCrate, recuperas tus argumentos y listo, ya los tienes del otro lado, puedes hacer lo que necesites hacer con ellos

```
@Override
```

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
if (getArguments() != null) {
    String titulo = getArguments().getString(TITLE_KEY);
    String descripcion = getArguments().getString(DESCRIPTION_KEY);
}
```

}

> Espero te sirva esta explicación
> **> Saludos**

Answer (score 0):

```
         CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, cuidades);
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
detalle(cuidades.get(position));

Comment: Seria ideal  que explicara esta respuesta, de lo contrario no va ser bien recibida